# Map Array of Array?

Tags: node.js

I have a crazy array look like this:

```
const data = [
     [{ Name: 'Name 1', Block: [{Id: "1"}, {Id: "2"}] }],
     [{ Name: 'Name 2', Block: [{Id: "3"}, {Id: "4"}] }],
]
```

I want to map `Block` to a single array to look like this:

```
[  { Id: '1' },
   { Id: '2' },
   { Id: '3' }, 
   { Id: '4' }
]
```

I have tried doing like this:

```js
const data = [
     [{ Name: 'Name 1', Block: [{Id: "1"}, {Id: "2"}] }],
     [{ Name: 'Name 2', Block: [{Id: "3"}, {Id: "4"}] }],
]


const idList = data.map(blockData => {
   return blockData[0].Block;
});

console.log(idList)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` will create a new item *for every index of the old array*. If your input array has 2 items, the output array will also only have 2 items - but you want 4 items, so `.map` won't work. Use `flatMap` instead, to flatten:

```js
const data = [
     [{ Name: 'Name 1', Block: [{Id: "1"}, {Id: "2"}] }],
     [{ Name: 'Name 2', Block: [{Id: "3"}, {Id: "4"}] }],
];

const idList = data.flatMap(([{ Block }]) => Block);

console.log(idList)
```

`flatMap` is only implemented on newer implementations, though - otherwise, use a polyfill or a different method, like `reduce`ing into an array:

```js
const data = [
     [{ Name: 'Name 1', Block: [{Id: "1"}, {Id: "2"}] }],
     [{ Name: 'Name 2', Block: [{Id: "3"}, {Id: "4"}] }],
];

const idList = data.reduce((a, [{ Block }]) => a.concat(Block), []);

console.log(idList)
```

Answer (score 0):

your data is an array inside array so you should use map twice, Buth that will give you an array with 2 elements now you need to reduce or flatten the resulting array to get the desired output.

```
data.map(a=>{return a[0].Block.map(b=>{ return b})}).reduce((o, m) => [...m, ...o], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct way to do it would be with a reduce statement:

```
const reducer = (a, b) => a.concat(b[0].Block);
const idList = data.reduce(reducer, []);
```

This way it will be much clearer what you are trying to do.